# How to solve linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, xcode6

I am getting this below error when am running in Xcode 6.3. how to solve this error

```
ld: entry point (start) undefined.  Usually in crt1.o for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: you need to add more description of the error. This error can be found in many scenario's (file missing, library search path error). Try pasting the complete error text here.

Comment: I believe you should go to your project settings, then your target and ensure you set the Architectures and Valid Architectures.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have stetted the Initial `UIViewController`. If not select any `UIViewController` and set it as Initial `UIViewController`r.

Answer (score 0):

Set your **root view controller** in **Appdelegate.m** `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method this is if your using xib(s) in your project.If your using a **storyboard** structure set the screen you would like to show on the launch of your application as the **initial view controller** in storyboard.